# how to use dynamic stirng array in c

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

i wish to store n number of words to an array. I used pointer in the following code to do that .But the problem is that once all words are read the words are not able to print.

please provide any solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char buff[10];
    int i,T;
    printf("Enter the  no.of words:");
    scanf("%d",&T);

    char **word= malloc(10*T);  
    printf("Enter the words:\n");
    for(i=0;i<T ;i++){
        scanf("%s",buff);
        word[i]= malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
        word[i]=buff;
        printf("u entered %s\n",word[i]);
        if(i>0)
            printf("u entered %s\n",word[i-1]);
    }

    printf("Entered words are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<T ;i++)
        printf("%s\n",word[i]);


}
```

Comment: The problem is you are storing the *same* `buff` pointer to each array element. That obviously means they all contain the same value and also causes a memory leak as the `malloc` buffer is lost. Use `strcpy` or `strdup`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to allocate size of `char *` -

```
char **word= malloc(sizeof(char *)*T);
```

And to copy string you need to use `strcpy`. So instead of this -

```
word[i]=buff;          // 1
```

use this -

```
strcpy(word[i],buff);         // include string.h header
```

By `1.` you point to `buff` using a pointer but the value stored in `buff` changes. So value to which all pointers point is same and you get all same output i.e the most recent value stored in `buff`.

Comment: @kilowatt glad it hlped.